# Cannot embed SSRS 2016 on SharePoint Online and Onprem WSS 3.0 and 2010

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation, reporting-services

Normally we can embed SSRS 2012 or later reports from SharePoint WSS 3.0 to 2013 Site but now when we tried the new SSRS 2016 it displays below error even in SharePoint Online.

Is there any way we can display it? Upgrading to SharePoint 2016 is not an option to us. Thanks!

I added SSRS 2016 and 2012 report on same page in SharePoint 2013 and only 2012 shows.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an Internet Explorer issue, not SharePoint or SSRS.

Add your SSRS server to your IE Trusted Sites list IE Internet Options and it should display it.

**Additional info:**

I am posting a screen shot below.

What are you using for your URL? I can reproduce your issue if I use this URL:

```
https://reports.mydomain.com/Reports/report/MyReportFolder/MyReport
```

However, it works when I use this form of URL Access, it works:

https://reports.mydomain.com/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?/MyReportFolder/MyReport

[image]

Comment: I already did that and still the same for SSRS 2016.

Comment: I’m doing it with SP 2013 and SSRS 2016 and it works just fine for me. Both are in Trusted Sites, and both are using https.

Comment: can you post screen shot

Comment: See my edits to my answer. Your problem may be the form of the URL you are using.  I reproduced your problem by copying the URL out of the report viewer, but if you use ReportViewer.aspx and URL Access, it works.

Comment: Thanks I got It working in 2013 but SRRS 2016 really not working on WSS 3.0 and 2010 version though

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint 2013 support, including Power view integration, requires the Reporting Services report server and the Reporting Services add-in version of SQL Server 2012 SP1 **or later**.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/install-windows/supported-combinations-of-sharepoint-and-reporting-services-server .

It's not version issue . You can compare the results using Fiddler , compare the Fiddler trace when you using SSRS 2012 and 2016 then you will found the root cause .

One possible solution would be :

1. Open the file C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\ReportServer\RSViewerPage.aspx in Notepad
2. Add the following line under the other <@ Register lines of code

<%@ Register Tagprefix="WebPartPages" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>

3. Save the file, then perform an IISReset and try the Iframe test again

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/officeapps/2012/12/12/iframing-sharepoint-hosted-pages-in-apps/

Answer (score 0):

You can use ThorApps BI Service host your ssrs reports in SharePoint Online. Its available from the Sharepoint AppStore.

Adrian